# Updating scope variable when factory updates in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to AngularJS and currently using Google Firebase for my real-time app. I have created a factory "Friends" which checks my Firebase database in real-time with the following code:

```
angular.module('App')

.factory('friendsFactory', function(){

   var friends = [];
   var friendshipRef = firebase.database().ref('friendships');

   friendshipRef.on('value', function(snapshot){

   //etc.. updates friends array

   });

   return{
      getFriends: function(){
        return friends;
      },
      //etc
   }
```

In my controller I set my `$scope.friends` variable to my factory class `.getFriends()` method. This works well and my page displays all friends correctly.

```
$scope.friends = friendsFactory.getFriends();
```

However, as soon as my factory is updated, these changes do not reflect on my scope variable and view. I've tried using `$apply`, `$watch` etc. but I cannot figure out how I can make sure my scope and view are updated as soon as the factory is. Right now, every time I navigate to a different page and back, only then the changes are shown. They do not update in real-time. Can anyone help me accomplish this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show how you update the `friends` array?

Comment: `$watch` should work perfectly. Can you show how you are using watch in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Because, you get list only once, at start.

It is necessary to make `$scope.$apply` in `on` section, but it is not right to do in the factory.

Try to use [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire)

Fast solution, will work:

```
angular.module('App')
.factory('friendsFactory', function(){

   var friends = [];
   var friendshipRef = firebase.database().ref('friendships');

   friendshipRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
       $timeout(function () {
           //etc.. updates friends array
       });
   });

   return{
      friends: friends,
      //etc
   }
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.friends = friendsFactory.friends;
```

Comment: I just tried your solution, but it's currently returning nothing at all actually, $scope.friends is empty

Comment: It is necessary to make `$scope.$apply` in `on` section, but it is not right to do in the factory. Try to use this: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire for angluar-way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this using [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) which does the three way binding between firebase database, your model and view.

1.Include [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) in your project.

2.Update your factory according to this and you don't need to do anything. Whenever data is updated on `friendships` node in firebase database, it will be notified to angularfire and angularfire will update the local variables and call `$scope.$apply` and thus, view will also be updated.

```
// factory
angular.module('App', ['firebase'])

.factory('friendsFactory', function($firebaseArray){
   var friendshipRef = firebase.database().ref('friendships');

   return {
       friends: $firebaseArray(friendshipRef)
   }
});

// controller
$scope.friends = friendsFactory.friends;
```